# Add or Remove HTML code on Windows Resize

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a responsive website. I'm using CSS Media Queries and Adaptive Images (http://adaptive-images.com/) to render each page correctly on different devices.

My problem is that some elements are downloaded by the browser even if there are hidden! For instance, a  element with the property {display:none;} is downloaded despite the fact that I don't want it.

So, here is my question: is there a way to add or remove HTML code depending on the device's screen-size?

By reading the code of  "Adaptive Images" script, I saw they used a cookie, which stores the screen-size value.

```
    <script>
    document.cookie='resolution='+(window.innerWidth)+'; path=/';
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        document.cookie='resolution='+(window.innerWidth)+'; path=/';
    }, false);
    </script>
```

So, I tried to read this cookie with a PHP function:

```
<?php 
    $fallback_res = 481; 
    $res = !empty($_COOKIE['resolution']) ? $_COOKIE['resolution'] :  
    $fallback_resolution; // Get the viewport resolution in $res variable
?>
```

It allows me to write a very useful PHP condition :

```
<?php if(isset($res) AND $res >= $fallback_res) // if viewport >= 481px
{
        echo '<video>...</video>'; // Display the video 
}
else { //if the screen is smaller
    echo ''; // Echo something else 
}

?>
```

It work very well. If the viewport is < 481px, the video is not downloaded. If the viewport is > 481px, the video is downloaded. But it only works, on page load!  If I load the page with a 480-wide-opened-browser (=video not loaded), and then resize my browser to higher resolution, there is a big hole in the middle of the page.

What I need is to reload some part of the code on window resize. (Each time I resize the browser window, I want the $res condition to be updated automatically, and the following code as well)

Thanks.

Comment: You have to ask yourself how many of your users will be resizing the page like this? Is it worth the extra code? You can add JavaScript that will react to a page resize and cause downloads to occur (but not the reverse, you cannot undo an http request AFAIK),

Comment: Yes, I already had this argument with an UX Expert in my company. We found several cases where this kind of code is necessary :
1) When the user  switch his browser to full window mode. 
2) When a two screens equiped user move the browser window from a small screen to a bigger one (or the other way round)
3) When the user resize the browser

Comment: They are viewing on screens less than 481px on a two screen environment? Sounds like there are other issues.

Comment: You are right on that point !

Answer (score 3):

if you combine blow jquery code with ajax , maybe you can do that .

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 480 )
    {
        #ajax code for download video
        #or use .after in jquery 
    }
})
```

Comment: The other issue is : what about a google robot, crossing this kind of JS generated page? I suppose a robot doesn't have a window width. What if I want it, to access the full version of my website ?

In this case, it's better to write the full HTML page, with all the elements but remove some when a small resolution is detected. 

Am I right ?

Comment: If the browser is resized smaller, you won't gain much by removing elements vs hiding them. What if they start full screen, resize smaller and then go back to full screen? It's better to load additional elements when needed and hide when not needed.

Comment: look at this too . that's about "width" and "height" on devices       http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/

Comment: at jrummell : I note "It's better to load additional elements when needed and hide when not needed".
at perdickss : Thank you, very useful. I'll check different methods to find the most efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Html will looks like

```
<div id="phone">Content For the below 450px </div>
<div id="desktop">Content For the above 450px </div>
```

Add jQuery

```
if($(window).width() < 450 )
    {
        $('#desktop').remove();
    }
     else 
   {
        $('#phone').remove();
   }
```

Comment: Clever. The next big problem is : how to use it on meta or script element ? There are some script, i don't need to load on small device (like Masonry, ScrollTo, Flexislider). How to do that ?